# How to show an excel button that allows the users to download the results in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I want to show an excel button that allows the users to download the results.

I want the users to download the table data shown in the workbook. The user should be able to download the filtered data.

For example if he selects regions as 'America', then in the excel sheet he must get only the data having 'America' as the region.

Please help me in achieving this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your dashboard is complete, just drag the download component (lower left corner in Object section), and set it for cross-tab (default is PDF).

[image]

This feature will be available if your dashboard is published on Tableau Server/Online and it will download the current data depending of what users see when they click on the download button.

Answer (score 2):

The **short answer** is that you can't.
Unfortunately, there's not Excel download button like download PDF for the moment.

The **long answer** is about two workarounds that you can follow:

- if you're using Tableau Server you can simply add `.csv` to your view's URL to make it downloadable in CSV. For example `http://tableauservercompany/#/myview` will become `http://tableauservercompany/#/myview.csv`. You can also apply filters as described in [this](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_structure.htm) tutorial.
- another workaround is to include in your workbook a worksheet (not a dashboard) with the table you want to let users download to Excel. In this way users can go to Download and select Excel file.